# Why should I evaluate derivative of SO(2) rotation in 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

I have stumbled upon [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793026/why-isnt-the-derivative-of-a-rotation-matrix-skew-symmetric) question and have a quetion to that. Short summary here. Say, I have an SO(2) rotation represeted by

$$R(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}$$

If I take a derivative of this matrix elementwise it is not skew symmetric. However, in the linked thread the answer suggests that I should evaluate the result in $\theta = 0$ which makes the resulting matrix skew symmetric. My question is why is that so? Is there a nice illustrative explanation on that? Or could you at least point me where to read about it. Thanks!

Comment: A useful reference (since you're coming at this from the matrix side) is Brian C. Hall's book on Lie Groups/Lie Algebras. The key point is that the Lie algebra to a Lie group can be thought of as its tangent space **at the identity**.

Comment: ah! Ok, your sentense about the Lie algebra with relation to Lie group clicks. I somehow dod not think about it. Totally makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the derivative works entry-wise, yielding
$$R'(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix}-\sin \theta&-\cos\theta\\\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\end{pmatrix}.$$
In general this is indeed not skew-symmetric. 
However, if we want to investigate the tangential space **at the identity** of $SO(2)$, then we have to evaluate $R'(\theta)$ at the one $\theta$ that belongs to $R(\theta)=I$, that is $\theta=0$. In that case $R(\theta)$ *is* skew-symmetric. We conclude that the tangential space at the identity consists precisely of the skew-symmetric matrices.